# Stop Bufferedreader Process

Tags: java, bufferedreader

my packet capture command in linux terminal..

```
sudo tcpdump -w kbh-ns.pcap -i lo greater 106 and less 106
```

Process will stop and save captured packet when i Press

> ^c

I have a code as below that uses BufferedReader to do it

```
public void SaveCapture() throws IOException
{
    List<String> command1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    //perintah untuk mecari koneksi ( SIP DIP SPort DPort )
    command1.clear();
    command1.add("sudo"); command1.add("tcpdump");
    command1.add("-w"); command1.add("kbh-ns.pcap"); //write
    command1.add("-i"); command1.add("vmnet1"); //interface
    command1.add("greater");command1.add("106"); //packet length
    command1.add("and");
    command1.add("less"); command1.add("106");//packet length
    command1.add("-c"); command1.add("20");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command1);
    process = pb.start();
    ProcessBuilder PB = new ProcessBuilder(command1);
    Process TerminalTask = PB.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String s;
    s = stdInput.readLine();
}
```

it works if i use

```
command1.add("-c"); command1.add("5");//number of packets to capture
```

my quetion :
How to make process stop with ^c command with java?

if i use `process.destroy()`

```
private void ButtonStopScanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    if (process != null)
    {
        process.destroy();
        TxtAreaKet.setText(TxtAreaKet.getText() + "Complete.. \n");
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        ReadPacket();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Receiver1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    TxtAreaKet.setText(TxtAreaKet.getText() + "waktu : "+ ((end - start) / 1000.0) + " ms");        
} 

private void ReadPacket() throws IOException {
    List<String> command1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    //perintah untuk mecari koneksi ( SIP DIP SPort DPort )
    command1.clear();
    command1.add("sudo"); command1.add("tcpdump");
    command1.add("-r"); command1.add("kbh-ns.pcap"); //read
    command1.add("-n"); 

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command1);
    process2 = pb.start();
    ProcessBuilder PB = new ProcessBuilder(command1);
    Process TerminalTask = PB.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process2.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process2.getErrorStream()));

    String s;
    long a = 0;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
        a++;
    }
    TxtAreaKet.setText(TxtAreaKet.getText() + "Captured Packet : " + a + "\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
        TxtAreaKet.setText(TxtAreaKet.getText() + s + "\n");
    }
}
```

that's not really stop my process because..

[image]

when i press `Stop Scan` again

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make process stop with ^c command with java?

Just call `Process.destroy()`.

Comment: thanks EJP..`Process.destroy()` make me can open file `kbh-ns.pcap` but `Process.destroy` its'nt really stop my capture process..

Comment: Process.destroy() is functionally equivalent to Ctrl/c. I suspect there is more you haven't told us.